# Criando um controller em angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou montando um `controller` onde uma das funcionalidades é pegar um dado no banco através do seu id. Porém, não aparece nada no console quando coloco isso

Código que exibe os paises na tela

```
<table width="200">
    <tr>
        <td><b>País</b></td>
        <td><b>Sala</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pais in paises">
        <td>{{pais.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{pais.sala}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/editarPais/{{pais.idPais}}">editar</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Código html

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="pais.idPais">
    País <input type="text" ng-model="pais.nome">
    Sala <input type="text" ng-model="pais.sala">
    <button ng-click="atualizarPais(pais)">Atualizar</button><br>
</form>
```

Código agunlar

```
app.controller("PaisesController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $state) {

var carregaPaises = function () {
    $http.get("admin/php/pegaPaises.php").success(function (data){
        //console.log(data);
        $scope.paises = data;
    });
};

$scope.adicionaPais = function (pais) {
    $http.post("admin/php/adicionaPais.php", pais).then(function (data){
        //console.log(data);
        carregaPaises();
    })
};

var carregaPais = function (pais) {
    console.log($routeParams.pais);
};

carregaPaises();

carregaPais();

});
```

Código do config:

```
var app = angular.module("vc", ["ui.router", "ngRoute"]);
.state("paises", {
        url: "/paises",
        controller: "PaisesController",
        templateUrl: "admin/views/paises.html"
    })

    .state("editarPais", {
        url: "/editarPais/:idPais",
        controller: "editarPaisController",
        templateUrl: "admin/views/editarPais.html"
    })
```

Como faço para ver os dados que vem no parâmetro?

Comment: Exatamente Celso.
Pois já usei isso em outro código e funcionou.

Comment: Está meio confuso.. Esse parâmetro deve vir de onde? da URL ou do formulário? Baseado nas suas questões anteriores, você está usando `ui-router` certo? E você só precisa pegar o parâmetro da URL, certo?

Comment: Sim, deverá vir do formulário e estou usando ui-router.
Não sei como funciona no angular, se os parâmetros vem via url.

Comment: Se ele vem do formulário, então não tem nada a ver com o parâmetro de URL, é isso? Você precisa apenas pegar o ID que está no input hidden do formulário?

Comment: Exatamente Celso.
E desconsidere aquele botão com ng-click"atualizarPais(pais)", pois não está sendo usado agora.
Agora quero carregar os dados no formulário para edição.

Comment: Então por enquanto é impossível fazer isso, pois os dados ainda não existem no formulário, logo, não temos como obter o ID. Ou você passa essa variável através de uma var global, ou coockie, ou parametro de url mesmo.

Comment: Celso, eu tinha esquecido de colocar os códigos da tela que exibem os paises e seus respectivos botões de editar com seus ids.
Dê uma olhada no enunciado do post. Desculpe.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema pode ser devido à uma falha de injeção do parâmetro. Tente usar `$routeParams` na injeção do `controller`, assim:

```
app.controller("editarPaisController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
```

Mas não sei como você está fazendo a definição do parâmetro na url, pois esse não é o método `Angular` de se definir um parâmetro. Como você disse que está utilizando o `ui-router`, recomendo que faça do modo correto, inclusive o link de acesso, onde deve ser feito da seguinte maneira:

html

```
<td><a ui-sref="meuestado({idPais: pais.idPais})">editar</a></td>
```

controller

```
app.controller("editarPaisController", function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    var urlParam = $state.params.idPais;
});
```

State

```
.state('meuestado', {
    url: 'editarPais/:idPais',
    //..outras opções aqui
})
```

Comment: Apareceu isso no console:
"Error: Could not resolve 'meuestado' from state 'paises'"

Comment: mas dai você tem que usar o estado referente aquela página de edição, eu defini apenas um exemplo. Você deve fazer a adaptação ao seu cenário.

Comment: Para não deixar tudo espalhado... Eu já tenho um controller que salvar os paises no banco e exibe na tela.
Eu posso pegar e juntar os comando do "editarPaisController" e colocar junto do outro, não?

Comment: Isso fica 100% a seu critério. Já vi artigos de pessoas que usam controllers bem segmentados, enquanto outros agrupam todas as funções de determinada área em um único. Faça como você achar melhor. Por exemplo, funções referente aos países no controller `paisesCtrl`, vai funcionar da mesma forma que segmentar.

Comment: Veja como está o código das routas... Coloquei no post. EU já tinha feito isso que vc sugeriu.

Comment: Sim, perfeito. Basta mudar o modo como você acessa essa página, veja a minha resposta na parte de html, apenas mude 'meuestado' para 'editarPais', que é o seu `state` de edição.

Comment: Mudei o meu controller, coloquei tudo em um controller só, veja na descrição do post que eu atualizei.

Comment: Ok, mas você ainda está usando o `ngRoute`. Recomendo que você utilize ou o `ngRoute` ou o `ui-router`. Para o ui, a minha resposta vai funcionar, basta você adaptar a função de carregar o parâmetro no controller. Para o `ngRoute`, você deve apenas verificar como definir o parâmetro. Mas a partir dali você já consegue montar, pois agora é só adaptar o seu fluxo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34156/discussion-between-gustavosevero-and-celsomtrindade).

Comment: Celso, to perdido... Como trabalho com isso?

Comment: Celso, mudei para:
"app.controller("PaisesController", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {"
e deu certo.

Comment: Sim, é outro método que também da certo. Eu uso pelo $state.params pois faço outras funções a partir dele. Mas se deu certo, perfeito.